# map image is not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google API to display the Map in my website but it is not displaying properly.

Api link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

This is my code to call google api.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 6,
       center: latlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       zoomControl: true,
       mapTypeControl: true,
       mapMaker:true
     };
var mapInstance = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:mapInstance,
      draggable:true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latlng
});
```

See one vertical white line is coming.How to remove that line??

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a complete DOCTYPE for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

set both the body AND html tags to 100% height

```
<style> 
html, body

{ height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

Out of curiosity...does this show in all browsers or just on IE.  Can you check Firefox?

Comment: Thanks for replying colorado...i have changed the tags but Still same line is coming......and yes it is showing in Mozilla also